# Report: Google Talk Plugin is not working and showing in Firefox 52.0 but works in Firefox 51.0.1

Tags: firefox, plugins, google-talk

Reporting that Google Talk Plugin works and shows in Firefox 51.0.1 (64bit), but not in Firefox 52.0 (64bit).

Process: Google Talk Plugin (5.41.3.0-1 (stable)) installed from repository http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main.  The plugin remains installed but does not show up in Firefox 52.0 addons and calls cannot be made, but shows up in Firefox 51.0.1 and calls can be made.

On cloned copies of same OS (Ubuntu 14.04.5) with same updated kernel (4.4.0-67-generic) Firefox 51.0.1 showed google-talkplugin in add-ons and the add-on allowed phone calls to be made in gmail.  Once Firefox was updated to Firefox 52.0, the google-talkplugin disappeared from Firefox add-ons yet remained installed as shown in Synaptic.

I reinstalled plugin (5.41.3.0-1 (stable)) from same repository, reinstalled Firefox 52.0 and plugin remained missing from Firefox add-ons. Removed Firefox 52.0 and reinstalled Firefox 51.0.1 and previously installed google-talkplugin reappeared in Firefox addons and calls could be made.

I don't think this is a bug or OS problem. Probably by design in Firefox version 52.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netflix on firefox 52](http://askubuntu.com/questions/892743/netflix-on-firefox-52)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Mozilla removed support for most plugins in Firefox 52. However, you can make it work a bit longer by adding a preference to `about:config`; please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892743/netflix-on-firefox-52/892970#892970).

Related:

[Google Hangouts temporarily won’t support phone and video calls on Mozilla Firefox](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/google-hangouts-temporary-issues-with-firefox.html)